# Unable to use Handlebars.js each helper with a Google Sheet feed fetched by Tabletop.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Well, I can't make the #each helper work, I think I know why but I have not sufficient Javascript knowledge to fix it.

Here is the data I am using listed when I list it in the console (it comes from a Google Sheet via Tabletop.js) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODYJx.png

I can use this data in my page for basic templating. But I also need to use the each helper to list all available entries, using a partial named "available_fights".

```
{{#each XXXX}}
{{> available_fights }}
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that with this data structure I do not know what value I can use for XXXX. I tried "this", Array, Object but it did not work.

Maybe I must format the data differently first and then use it in Handlebars ?

Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your variable with the array is called fights

You can simply do:

```
{{#each fights}}
{{this.adv1legend}}
...
{{/each}}
```